# Ruby CSV.open will create file if one does not exist?

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm generating a CSV file in Ruby with data from my database. I was using CSV.open(filename, "w") do |csv|

Will that create a file with that filename if one does not exist?

Comment: Let's find out: `require 'csv'; CSV.open('Taylor', 'w') {}; File.file?('Taylor') #=> true; File.size('Taylor') #=> 0`.

Comment: It will also truncate (empty) the file if it does exist, no questions asked. Research IO.open modes for other options besides "w".

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the options you specify when you call `CSV.open()`.

If you call it with a `"r"` (read only) mode argument, then you will get an error:

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - your_file_name.ext

If, however, you use the `"w"` (write) or `"wb"` (write binary) option, Ruby will create the file for you.

`CSV.open("my_new_file.csv", "r")` --> will fail if file does not exist

`CSV.open("my_new_file.csv", "w")` --> will create a new file